# Is there a way to prevent an iframe from redirecting parent window, but in such a way that "top level" redirects still work inside the iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

So I've read about the [HTML5 `sandbox` property](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) and I understand that if I want to prevent an iframe redirect its parent window I can use the `sandbox` property leaving `allow-top-navigation` out. However when this is done, if the iframe was originally relying on top level redirection, what happens in its place is that it redirects to a blank page, effectively breaking navigation.

Can I prevent the iframe from tinkering its parent window while still allowing "top level" redirects, only letting these work within the context of the iframe instead of being top level?

Edit: For context, I'm working with a third party and its page has a form with a target `_top`. If the iframe is sandboxed, upon submitting the form users get a blank page, if it's *not* sandboxed the entire page is redirected. I'm looking for something that would allow to submit the form and show the result within the iframe itself.

Comment: Are you sure that the redirected contents would still work inside the iframe? If you try doing this to PayPal payment page for instance, it would break.

Comment: What would be great is if the IFrame `sandbox` attribute had a value such as `allow-top-navigation-here` which would result in the IFrame being used as the target for a `window.top` operation.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @geo sort of, I resorted to loading the content in a popup (as in, an actual separate window via `window.open`), and that worked for my needs, but I didn't find a pure iframe solution.

Comment: Any solution for this problem in 2019? almost 2020

Comment: Any solution on this so far?

Answer (score 5):

With **HTML5** the [iframe sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) attribute was added.

At the time of writing this [works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and recent versions of IE and Opera](http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox) but does pretty much what you want:

### Allows the iframe content to be treated as being from the same origin as the containing document

```
<iframe src="url" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

---

**Browser Compatibility**
[image]

---

**Some Useful links**

- [w3schools for sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)
- [developer.mozilla.org iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
  -

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` property and determine if you wan to redirect or not.

[Here is the docs page for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload)

Basically what I would try is this:

- Make a function that adds the sandbox attribute with everything, just leaving out the `allow-top-navigation`, to the iframe
- Bind a function to the `onbeforeunload` property of the iframe that calls the function that adds the sandbox attribute (be sure not to return anything because a dialog will pop-up)

This should work because the request is made in the iframe first, and then we can prevent it from carrying over to our top level window.

Another thing you should check is if you maybe left out the `allow-forms`option, which can cause what you are describing.

Please let me know if any of this worked.

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting but `onbeforeunload` doesn't seem to be firing when `allow-top-navigation` is left out.

Comment: But wait, if you added the sandbox attribute in the `onbeforeunload` event itself (for the iframe), there is no way it is not fired.
Also another way that I'm 80% will work is this:
Through javascript/jQuery, when the iframe is done loading, select the form element and change target attribute to `_self`.

Comment: By default, not including `allow-top-navigation` means no redirections happen on the top level, which in turn does not trigger `onbeforeunload`.

Comment: But have you tried changing the target attribute on the form in question?

Comment: The form in question is outside of my control, it's in an external iframe that I don't access to.

Comment: You should bring this up with the third party vendor. The target of the form sounds like it should be some sort of configurable option in the query string that loads the page in the iframe.