# Prevent malware ads redirects on mobile website

Tags: javascript, ads, malware-detection

I have a problem with malicious ads on my mobile website, which redirects the user to app store. Mainly on the android browser and Safari for iOS.

Is there a way to block redirects for e.g. using javascript ?
Maybe some event with preventDefault() function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent IFRAME from redirecting top-level window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958241/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-an-iframe-from-redirecting-parent-window-but-in-such or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578767/prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-parent-page